# Why single date selection isn't working and always returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I'm currently working on implementing a date selection feature in my Quasar application using the q-input and q-date components. The goal is to enable users to pick either a single date or a date range. However, I've encountered an issue specifically with the single date selection functionality.

Problem Statement:

Expected Behavior:
Date Range Selection: Successfully selects and retrieves the range of dates as expected.
Single Date Selection: Expected to retrieve the chosen single date; however, it consistently returns undefined.
Code Overview:

Here's a simplified representation of the code structure I've implemented:

```
<!-- q-input to trigger date selection -->
<q-input label="Date Selection" outlined dense>
  <q-date v-if="isRange" v-model="date_interval" mask="YYYY-MM-DD" range>...</q-date>
  <q-date v-else v-model="single_date" mask="YYYY-MM-DD">...</q-date>
</q-input>
```

```
// Relevant Vue setup
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isRange: true,
      date_interval: { from: null, to: null }, // Used for date range
      single_date: null, // Intended for single date selection
    };
  },
  methods: {
    // Method to handle updating selected date(s)
    updateDate() {
      // Logic to handle updating date_interval for range or single_date for single selection
    },
    // Other relevant methods for handling functionality
    // ...
  },
};
```

Attempts Made:

Implemented watchers to track changes in single_date and date_interval.
Reviewed documentation and examples for q-date usage in Quasar framework.
Request for Assistance:

I'm seeking guidance on resolving this issue with the single date selection consistently returning undefined. Any insights, suggestions, or examples on how to properly retrieve the selected single date using the q-date component would be immensely helpful.

Thank you for your time and help!

```
<template>
  <div class="row q-gutter-xs q-pa-xs q-pt-sm">
    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <q-input label="Date Selection" class="date-input" outlined dense>
        <template v-slot:append>
          <q-icon name="event" class="cursor-pointer">
            <q-popup-proxy cover transition-show="scale" transition-hide="scale">
              <q-date v-if="isRange" v-model="date_interval" mask="YYYY-MM-DD" range>
                <div class="row items-center justify-end">
                  <q-btn v-close-popup label="Close" color="primary" flat />
                  <q-btn v-close-popup label="OK" @click="updateDate" color="primary" flat />
                </div>
              </q-date>
              <q-date v-else v-model="single_date" mask="YYYY-MM-DD">
                <div class="row items-center justify-end">
                  <q-btn v-close-popup label="Close" color="primary" flat />
                  <q-btn v-close-popup label="OK" @click="updateSingleDate" color="primary" flat />
                </div>
              </q-date>
            </q-popup-proxy>
          </q-icon>
        </template>
      </q-input>
    </div>

    <q-space />

    <div align="right" class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
        <q-select style="width: 130px; margin-right: 20px" options-selected-class="text-deep-primary" options-dense
          v-model="selectedCurrency" outlined dense :options="options" label="Currency" class="currency-select">
          <template v-slot:prepend>
            <div style="padding-top: 13px">
              <q-icon name="money" size="20px" color="black" />
            </div>
          </template>
        </q-select>

        <q-icon name="refresh" @click="forceReload" size="26px" style="margin-right: 20px"></q-icon>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <q-separator />

  <q-tabs v-model="tab" dense active-color="primary" indicator-color="primary" narrow-indicator scrollable align="left">
    <q-tab name="promotions" label="Promotions" />
    <q-tab name="plans" label="Plans" />
    <q-tab name="date" label="Date" />
    <q-tab name="hour" label="Hour" />
    <q-tab name="month" label="Month" />
  </q-tabs>

  <div class="q-py-sm q-gutter-y-xs">
    <q-tab-panels v-model="tab" animated>
      <q-tab-panel name="date">
        <data-table-builder groupBy="date" class="tab-panel-content">
        </data-table-builder>
      </q-tab-panel>
      <q-tab-panel name="hour">
        <data-table-builder groupBy="hour"> </data-table-builder>
      </q-tab-panel>
      <q-tab-panel name="month">
        <data-table-builder groupBy="month"> </data-table-builder>
      </q-tab-panel>
      <q-tab-panel name="promotions">
        <data-table-builder groupBy="affiliate_link_id"> </data-table-builder>
      </q-tab-panel>
      <q-tab-panel name="plans">
        <data-table-builder groupBy="plan_id"> </data-table-builder>
      </q-tab-panel>
    </q-tab-panels>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, watch } from 'vue';
import global from 'src/global';
import moment from "moment";
import DataTableBuilder from './DataTableBuilder.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    DataTableBuilder
  },
  setup() {
    const { state } = global;
    const options = ['USD', 'INR'];
    const selectedCurrency = ref(state.currency);
    const date_interval = ref({
      from: moment().local().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
      to: moment().local().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    });
    const isRange = ref(true); // Initially set to range selection
    const single_date = ref(moment().local().format("YYYY-MM-DD"));

    watch(
      () => state.currency,
      (newValue) => {
        selectedCurrency.value = newValue;
      }
    );

    watch(
      () => selectedCurrency.value,
      (newValue) => {
        state.currency = newValue;
      }
    );

    watch(
      () => date_interval.value,
      (newValue) => {
        if (!isRange.value) {
          single_date.value = newValue.from;
        }
      }
    );

    watch(
      () => single_date.value,
      (newValue) => {
        if (!isRange.value) {
          if (newValue !== date_interval.value.from) {
            date_interval.value = {
              from: newValue,
              to: newValue,
            };
          }
        }
      }
    );


    return {
      state,
      tab: ref("date"),
      date_interval,
      options,
      selectedCurrency,
      isRange,
      single_date,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updateDate() {
      this.date = this.date_interval;
      this.state.date = this.date;
    },
    updateSingleDate() {
      this.isRange = false;
      this.updateDate(); // Update the date based on single_date directly
      console.log('Single Date:', this.single_date);
      console.log('Date Interval:', this.date_interval);
    },
    updateCurrency(currency) {
      this.currency = currency;
      this.state.currency = currency;
    },
    forceReload() {
      this.state.refresh += 1;
    },
  },
};
</script>


<style lang="scss">
.q-tab-panel {
  padding: 7px;
}

.q-table--dense .q-table__top {
  padding: 6px 16px 0px 6px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.date-input.q-field--float .q-field__label {
  transform: translateY(-120%) translateX(-5px) scale(0.75);
  background: #fff;
  right: inherit;
  padding: 0 5px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.date-input.q-field--dense.q-field--float .q-field__label {
  transform: translateY(-85%) translateX(-5px) scale(0.75);
}

.date-input.q-field--labeled .q-field__native,
.date-input.q-field--labeled .q-field__prefix,
.date-input.q-field--labeled .q-field__suffix {
  padding-top: 8px;
}

.currency-select.q-field--float .q-field__label {
  transform: translateY(-120%) translateX(-5px) scale(0.75);
  background: #fff;
  right: inherit;
  padding: 0 5px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.currency-select.q-field--dense.q-field--float .q-field__label {
  transform: translateY(-85%) translateX(-5px) scale(0.75);
}

.currency-select.q-field--labeled .q-field__native,
.currency-select.q-field--labeled .q-field__prefix,
.currency-select.q-field--labeled .q-field__suffix {
  padding-top: 8px;
}
</style>
```